# Screen tearing when using i3, none when using unity

Tags: unity, graphics, compiz, i3-wm

I was attempting to use i3 on my ubuntu installation the other day. I noticed however that when I would logout and switch to using i3 I would start to see tearing when watching videos or scrolling through websites. This is something I do not notice when using unity. I would really like to be able to use i3 but currently cannot due to screen issues.

Would anyone have a suggestion as to what might be causing this? What ends up being different between i3 and unity as far as displaying the screen? Most of the threads I read about screen tearing referred to compiz. Wouldn't compiz be the same on both ubuntu and i3?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The *Unity Shell UI* is a plugin of the Compiz compositing window manager ([Unity Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Unity_Architecture.pdf)) while *i3* a standalone window manager without native compositing features. That means that by default *Unity* utilizes all manner of graphics acceleration features and *i3* uses "plain" X11.

---

In order to get compositing features in *i3*, you will have to start a composite manager (*not* a compositing window manager). *compton* is a quite popular choice to use with *i3*.

Installation is easy as packages for Ubuntu are available in the official repository for trusty and newer. After installation you have to create a configuration, for example at `~/.config/compton.conf` (as the location of the configuration file can be passed as argument to `compton`, the choice is yours). My `compton.conf` looks like this:

```
# basic configuration
backend = "glx";
vsync = "opengl-swc";

glx-copy-from-front = true;
glx-swap-method = 2;
xrender-sync = true;
xrender-sync-fence = true;

# transparancy settings for i3
opacity-rule = [
    "0:_NET_WM_STATE@:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
];
```

It is possible that you need to adjust it for your system.
Now you can start `compton`:

```
compton --config ~/.config/compton.conf -b
```

After you made sure that it works well, you can start it automatically by adding

```
exec --no-startup-id compton --config ~/.config/compton.conf -b
```

to your `~/.i3/config`.

**Note:** I strongly suggest updating *i3* to at least version 4.12 (the current release at time of posting). It solves a few rendering issues *i3* has in conjunction with *compton*, at least when *cairo* ≥ 1.14.4 is available (xenial comes with *cairo* 1.14.6; see [*i3* Release Notes](https://github.com/i3/i3/blob/4.12/RELEASE-NOTES-4.12)).

Comment: `compton` is a very nice lightweight compositor.

Comment: @Adaephon Thank you so much! This has been a headache of mine for a while.

Comment: Man, I'm so glad I found this answer. I had no idea the `backend` option existed. Setting it to `glx` basically fixed everything for me. All tearing is gone and browser scrolling is silky smooth.

Comment: I start compton as the first line in my i3 config and nothing has changed, I still get screen tearing in Chrome.

Comment: @Boris It does not really matter, where you put this in the i3-config. For one, there is no guarantee that the commands are executed in order nor does `i3` wait for any command to fully run before starting the next. For another, `compton` itself can be started at any point later in a running i3 session and should work just fine. That being said, I have noticed some screen tearing issues on multi-display setups, where the refresh rate of the displays does not match 100% (e.g. 59.97 Hz vs 60.01 Hz) and the output is synced to the "wrong" display. Unfortunately, I have not yet found a solution.